# How to properly push files from existing non-repository-based project to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm totally green on the git front. I've never used git before but I have a project folder (not in a repository, just file storage) that I'd like to upload to a gitlab repository. The new repository I made on gitlab comes automatically with an initial readme file as part of the first commit. However this seems to get in the way of uploading my files. When I try to push them, I get the error:

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally.

If I pull the gitlab repo I get the error:

> refusing to merge unrelated histories

I feel like whatever I do there's a sense of like "if it wasn't made in a repository it doesn't belong here", what am I doing wrong and how is one supposed to do this initial transfer of original files properly?

Comment: It's tricky when you've already initialised the project on GitLab or any SCM provider. Ideally, you would create a repository without initialising the README, Ignore or License if you're planning on pushing an existing code. That would then display relevant commands to put that code. Alternatively, you can try `git push -f` to forcefully push your local changes to remote, this will result in the README file from replaced or deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. An alternative I was thinking of was to make a local clone of the github repo, add the files locally and then pushing back to the remote, would that make any sense or am I talking crap now? :P

Comment: Yes, that's also an option, you just clone the repo to another place/folder, add the files and commit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as git is concerned, you have two different repositories, with unrelated histories: one on gitlab, with a commit to add the initial readme; and one locally, with all your code in it.

There are a few different things you can do:

- Delete the repository in gitlab and create a new one without the initial readme commit
- Clone the repository from gitlab into a new folder, copy your files in and commit them alongside the readme
- Commit your files locally and use "git pull --allow-unrelated-histories" to merge the branch with the readme on, even though it has no ancestors in common with your local repository
- Use "git push --force-with-lease" to overwrite the history on gitlab with your local version (discarding the commit where gitlab added the readme for you)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep that Readme file, you can rebase your branch on top of that initial commit :

```
git rebase --root origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd yourproject                    # make a repo for your project
git init                          # .
git remote add origin u://r/l     # set it up to talk to your gitlab repo
git pull --set-upstream origin master         # or maybe main instead of master
```

And you've now got the gitlab history checked out and can add and commit your project files normally.